# How do I configure the Core module without using the store module?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Below are our current configurations.  How would we configure, backend, authentication, context without going through storeConfig?

`B2cStorefrontModule.withConfig(environment.storeConfig),   ConfigModule.withConfigFactory(defaultCmsContentConfig),`

```
storeConfig: {
    backend: {
      occ: {
        baseUrl: 'https://localhost:9002',
        prefix: '/mywebservices/v2/'
      }
    },
    authentication: {
      client_id: 'myid',
      client_secret: 'mysecret'
    },

    context: {
      baseSite: ['mysite'],
      currency: ['USD'],
    },

    i18n: {
      resources: translations,
      chunks: translationChunksConfig,
      fallbackLang: 'en'

    }

  },
```

Comment: +1 because I would also like to know the answer.

@Netwobble What's the reason for this request? Are you planning to build your B2C storefront from scratch? Or , are you creating a B2B storefront?

Comment: Do you think this might help? https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/blob/storefront-1.3.0-next.4/projects/storefrontlib/src/recipes/storefront.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

You can import `provideConfig` from `@spartacus/core` and use it like this:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [ 
  ...
  provideConfig({
    // your config goes here
    backend: {
      occ: {
        baseUrl: 'https://localhost:9002',
        prefix: '/mywebservices/v2/'
      }
    },
    authentication: {
      client_id: 'myid',
      client_secret: 'mysecret'
    },
  }),
  ]
  ...
})
```

You can have as many `provideConfig()` as you want.